# Collapse toolbar scroll

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to make a layout with a CollapsingToolbarLayout which has scroll|exitUntilCollapsed flag, Collapsing toolbar is not scrolling properly i want it to scroll in continuity  pin toolbar and tab layout on top when scroll and make collapsing layout exit until collapsed. Currently collapsing layout enter when we scroll down the recycler view.

Xml code is here:

```
  <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/black">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/content_frame1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                                    android:elevation="10dp">

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:background="@color/black"
                                        android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <ImageView
                                            android:id="@+id/home_image"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                            android:src="@color/gray" />

                                        <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                                            android:orientation="vertical">

                                            <LinearLayout
                                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                android:weightSum="1">

                                                <TextView
                                                    android:id="@+id/home_txt_saloon_name"
                                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                                                    android:gravity="left"
                                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                                    android:textSize="@dimen/SmallTextSize" />

                                                <RelativeLayout
                                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                                                    android:gravity="center">

                                                    <ImageView
                                                        android:id="@+id/img_distance"
                                                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                                                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_address" />

                                                    <TextView
                                                        android:id="@+id/home_txt_distance"
                                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                                                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_distance"
                                                        android:text="0 km"
                                                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                                        android:textSize="@dimen/SmallTextSize" />

                                                </RelativeLayout>

                                                <TextView
                                                    android:id="@+id/txt_view_map"
                                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                                                    android:gravity="right|center"
                                                    android:text="@string/get_directions"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                                    android:textSize="@dimen/SmallTextSize" />

                                            </LinearLayout>

                                            <LinearLayout
                                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                android:weightSum="1">

                                                <LinearLayout
                                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                    android:weightSum=".4">

                                                    <ImageView
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".05"
                                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_heart" />

                                                    <TextView
                                                        android:id="@+id/home_text_heart"
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".08"
                                                        android:text="0"
                                                        android:textColor="@color/mustard"
                                                        android:textSize="@dimen/SmallTextSize" />

                                                    <ImageView
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".05"
                                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_share" />

                                                    <TextView
                                                        android:id="@+id/home_txt_share"
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".08"
                                                        android:text="0"
                                                        android:textColor="@color/mustard"
                                                        android:textSize="@dimen/SmallTextSize" />

                                                    <View
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".14" />

                                                </LinearLayout>

                                                <LinearLayout
                                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                                                    android:gravity="center"
                                                    android:weightSum=".3">

                                                    <ImageView
                                                        android:id="@+id/salon_img_drink"
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".05"
                                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_drink"
                                                        android:visibility="gone" />

                                                    <ImageView
                                                        android:id="@+id/salon_img_wifi"
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".05"
                                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_wifi"
                                                        android:visibility="gone" />

                                                    <ImageView
                                                        android:id="@+id/salon_img_paw"
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".05"
                                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_paw"
                                                        android:visibility="gone" />

                                                    <ImageView
                                                        android:id="@+id/salon_img_kid"
                                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".05"
                                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_kid"
                                                        android:visibility="gone" />

                                                </LinearLayout>

                                                <LinearLayout
                                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                                                    android:gravity="end">

                                                    <RatingBar
                                                        android:id="@+id/salon_ratingbar"
                                                        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                        android:numStars="5"
                                                        android:scaleX=".8"
                                                        android:scaleY=".8"
                                                        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"/>

                                                </LinearLayout>

                                            </LinearLayout>

                                        </LinearLayout>

                                    </LinearLayout>

                                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                            </LinearLayout>

                        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab_container"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/black"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/border"
                                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                                app:tabGravity="fill"
                                app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
                                app:tabMode="fixed"
                                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
                                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                                app:tabTextColor="@color/mustard" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@color/mustard"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/lay_back"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".1"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_back" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".1" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/saloon_txt_title"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".6"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/TitleTextSize" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/saloon_lay_fav"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".1"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/saloon_img_fav"
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/fav" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/saloon_lay_share"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".1"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_share_white" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/ButtonSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/mustard"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/salon_lay_contact"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/icon"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/phone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:text="@string/contact"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/NormalTextSize" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/salon_lay_book"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/icon1"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_salon" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/book_now"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/NormalTextSize" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```